# What is the complexity of the following code? And overloader function

Tags: c++

I am solving a problem where, from given list of dates, we have to print the third latest date.

`Input: [24-01-2001, 9-2-2068, 4-04-2019, 31-10-1943, 2-10-2013, 17-12-1990]`

`output:2-10-2013`

I have written the following code for it

```
using namespace std;

struct Date
{
    int Day;
    int Year;
    int Month;
};


 
// comparator function used during insertion in set
bool operator<(const Date& date1, const Date & date2)
{
        if(date1.Year<date2.Year)
                return true;
        if(date1.Year == date2.Year and date1.Month<date2.Month)
                return true;
        if(date1.Year == date2.Year and date1.Month==date2.Month and date1.Day<date2.Day)
                return true;
        return false;
}

Date ThirdLatest(std::vector<Date> & dates) {
       
        //using set data structure to eliminate duplicate dates
        set<struct Date>UniqueDates;
        
        
        //using operator function the dates are inserted into the 
        //set in a sorted manner
        for(auto i:dates)
        {
                UniqueDates.insert(i);
        }
        
        //clear original dates vector
        dates.clear();
        
        //push dates from the set back into dates vector
        for(auto i: UniqueDates)
        {
               dates.push_back(i);
        }
  
        int DatesSize=dates.size();
        return dates[DatesSize-3];
}
```

I was just wondering about the complexity of this code as this uses just an ordered set and elements are inserted into it using overloader function `operator<` to sort the dates instead of using the `sort()` function. Insertion into ordered set is `O(log n)` so is the complexity of this code also `log n` or am I calculating it wrong?

Also, I had one more question regarding the overloader function. I studied about overloader function from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-function-cpp/) that when the symbol is mentioned the function of that can be overpassed. But in this code, how does that work because for insertion into the set the symbol `<` is not mentioned anywhere in the code. The code works so how is `<` being used here?

Comment: Are you sure you can take `dates` by reference and then clobber it?

Comment: "is the complexity of this code also `log n` or am I calculating it wrong?" You are calculating it wrong.

Comment: "how does that work because for insertion into the set the symbol < is not mentioned anywhere in the code" Hint: `std::set` supports three template parameters, one that's required and two with default values. Take a look at the others.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica can you please tell me what is the complexity of the code?

Comment: Isn't that what your homework is to figure out?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica no no it's not my homework, it's from an online test I had given for a company and now I am reviewing my answers after that test has finished.

Comment: Ok, if that was an interview question, you failed to produce an ideal solution. Any ideal solution would have kept only the 3 latest dates in the accumulation buffer, in order to keep insertions constant rather than `log n`.

Comment: @Ext3h so by an accumulation buffer do you mean to have an answer vector of size 3 and traverse the dates array and keep updating the latest dates in the answer vector as in when we come across them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overloaded operator< as you are inserted elements into a sorted set. So, sorted set is implemented as red–black tree. Red-black tree is a kind of self-balancing binary search tree. Since, it is essentially a binary, insertion of each element would be of order O(log(n)). Insertion of n-elements would be order O(n*log(n)). The overloaded operator< is used for searching in binary tree. If the element is < then current element then search goes to left subtree and otherwise it goes to right subtree. The search is continued until element is found. Detailed explanation could be found here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/red-black-tree-set-1-introduction-2/.

Also instead of inserting element into set and then inserting them back in the vector, you could have sorted the existing vector itself using std::sort() method. That could be done using: std::sort(dates.begin(), dates.end()). You wouldn't require 3rd argument since you have already overloaded operator<. Refer to: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ for more details.

Also, it is fortunate that fields inside date all support operator< and operator==. However, in general it is not guaranteed so better to write any operator<() method by calling operator<() on its members like:

```
// comparator function used during insertion in set or by sort method
bool operator<(const Date& date1, const Date & date2)
{
    if(date1.Year < date2.Year)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(date2.Year < date1.Year)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Equality case for year
    if(date1.Month < date2.Month)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(date2.Month < date1.Month)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Equality case for year and month
    if(date1.Day < date2.Day)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(date2.Day < date1.Day)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Clearing the vector and pushing back all the elements also has a disadvantage that if the vector was reasonable large, on clearing it would become of smallest size possible, and get re-allocated and re-copied once it crosses the allocated memory. Even if you were do such operations, would recommend calling: vector.reserve() prior to inserting, or simply re-assigning all the values without clearing/pushing back.

And if your code requires processing of date frequently and requires entries to be ordered by date, I would recommend using: map/set instead of vector for storing dates.

Since the problem is to find 3rd largest date, rather than sorting all the elements by sorting entire vector or inserting all of them into a set, you would need to insert elements in to priority_queue of size 3. In general, to find Kth largest element, you need to maintain a priority_queue of size K. Priority queue is implemented as heap, which is completely balanced binary tree. It is not ordered like: AVL or Red-Black tree used in ordered sets and maps, but optimized for insertion, and even faster than ordered sets in this case.

Generally, the priority queue always have greatest elements first. So you would need to define a comparator so that it places smallest element at top which is required in your case.

```
template<class T>

class TestAscending
{
public:
    bool operator() (const Date& l, const Date&r) const
    {
        return r < l;
    }
};

// Somewhere in code you would define priority queue as
priority_queue<Date, vector<Date>, TestAscending<Date> > p;
```

So, you insert elements of vector into the priority_queue one by one. Until, the size of set is < k, you can add elements in the priority queue without any conditional check. When the size of the priority_queue (p.size()) becomes k, then you add element only when it is greater than top-most element of the priority queue (p.top()) (being the smallest). You do it by removing existing smallest by calling p.pop() and adding the new one with p.push().

At the end of the program topmost element p.top() will kth largest element.

Since, the priority is of size K, the complexity of program is reduced from O(n*log(n)) to O(n*log(k)) in the worst case. Since, priority queue is even faster than set in insertion, the complexity and execution time would be faster than using set of size k.

Comment: Welcome @alexderalu. Found that for this particular problem best solution is to use priority_queue of size 3, which is even better than ordered set of size 3 for determining kth smallest/greatest element. I have updated the answer accordingly.